# Error when using Grid field: You are not authorized to perform this action

Tags: error, grid, bug

Getting this error when attempting to use the Grid field: You are not authorized to perform this action

Once I switch to another field type, error goes away...

Comment: @GDmac Thanks, I went ahead and used Matrix. Disappointing that such a blatant bug made it past QA.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in 2.9.0 and will probably soonish be fixed in an update
See: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20462/grid-fieldtype-brings-up-warning-when-rows-are-present-on-entry-submit

(ps. bug report includes patch/fix)

Answer (score 0):

Also just ran into this bug on an E2.9.0 clean install. Just applied the fix mentioned in the post GDmac referenced here. It's working for me so far so good. I hope this helps.